# What is the difference between Draughts and Checkers?

Tags: terminology, checkers

Other than draughts is British English and checkers is American English, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 33):

"[Draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts)" is a family of closely related games, so you need to be more specific about exactly which game you mean.

- [English draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts) is *exactly* the same game as (American) checkers, the one played on an 8x8 board - and as someone brought up in the UK, I can confirm that is what people in the UK mean by "draughts".
- [International draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_draughts) (also called Polish draughts or international checkers) is the game played on a 10x10 board.

There is no "global" standard for these; in Italy, Latvia, Norway and the UK, the 8x8 version is the standard with the 10x10 version very rare, while in the Netherlands the 10x10 version is the standard with the 8x8 version being very rare.

Comment: However on the continent (and particularly in Netherlands in my experience) the 8x8 version is virtually unknown with only the 10x10 version played.

Comment: Norwegian here, and I have never, ever seen, and practically never heard of this game being played on anything other than a standard chessboard. So it's very much a regional thing.

Comment: In Italy we have "Dama" (8x8) and "Dama internazionale" (10x10). The 10x10 version is rarely played

Comment: Thanks folks, I've integrated those extra countries into the answer. Anybody else feel free to edit the answer to add the usage in other countries.

Comment: Latvian here. Today I learned that there are 10x10 boards somewhere out there. Cool!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know:

Draughts:

- Board is 10x10
- Normal pieces can jump backwards to take a piece
- Kings can move several squares in each direction

Checkers:

- Board is 8x8
- Normal pieces can not jump backwards to take a piece
- Kings can move 1 square in each direction. They can jump backwards to take a piece.

Comment: This may well be regional, but in the UK *draughts* is used for the game you've described as *checkers*. The game you described as *draughts* is something I've never encountered except on wikipedia.

Comment: Gotta be regional, the version I have seen in Russia has the rules of "Draughts" as described here but is played exclusively on 8x8.

Answer (score -2):

The only version of Draughts that you can capture on a back move is Brazilian Draughts, also the only game I am aware of with the Flying Kings that can move multiple spaces in a single move. Brazilian Draughts is played on an 8x8 board as well.